# Table performs a calculation only in the first row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've build an interactive table where you can manually add and delete rows (with bootstrap). This all works fine!

Now comes the problem:
I have some input fields with an automatic calculation. But the problem is, the table only performs the calculation in the standard row, and not in the addable row.

This is the .HTML and .JS of the table:

```js
jQuery(document).delegate('a.add-record_venr', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = jQuery('#sample_table_venr tr'),
    size = jQuery('#tbl_posts_venr >tbody >tr').length + 1,
    element = null,
    element = content.clone();
    element.attr('id', 'rec_venr-'+size);
    element.find('.delete-record_venr').attr('data-id', size);
    element.appendTo('#tbl_posts_body_venr');
    element.find('.sn').html(size);
    });
    jQuery(document).delegate('a.delete-record_venr', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var didConfirm = confirm("Ventilatierooster verwijderen?");
    if (didConfirm == true) {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
    var targetDiv = jQuery(this).attr('targetDiv');
    jQuery('#rec_venr-' + id).remove();
    
    //regnerate index number on table
    $('#tbl_posts_body_venr tr').each(function(index) {
    //alert(index);
    $(this).find('span.sn').html(index+1);
    });
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  

<div class="wellclearfix">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record_venr" data-added="0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Toevoegen </a>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left:1px ;">
                  <table class="table table-stripped" id="tbl_posts_venr">
                    <thead style="background-color:#c7c8cc; width: 100% !important;">
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width:30px ;">Merk</th>
                        <th >Lengte rooster</th>
                        <th >Type rooster</th>
                        <th >Capaciteit [dm3/s]</th>
                        <th >Max. capaciteit [dm3/s]</th>
                        <th >Verblijfsgebied</th>
                        <th >Verblijfsruimte</th>
                        <th >Verwijderen</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tbl_posts_body_venr">
                      <tr id="rec_venr-1">
                        <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Merk"> </td>
                        <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="lrooster" id="lrooster" placeholder="Lengte rooster"></td>
                        <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type rooster"></td>
                        <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="caprooster" id="caprooster" placeholder="Capaciteit [dm3/s]"></td>
                        <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="maxcaprooster" id="maxcaprooster" placeholder="Max. capaciteit [dm3/s]"></td>
                        <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Verblijfsgebied"></td>
                        <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Verblijfsruimte"></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>


              <div style="display:none;">
              <table id="sample_table_venr">
                <tr id="">
                  <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Merk"> </td>
                  <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="lrooster" id="lrooster" placeholder="Lengte rooster"></td>
                  <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type rooster"></td>
                  <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="caprooster" id="caprooster" placeholder="Capaciteit [dm3/s]"></td>
                  <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="maxcaprooster" id="maxcaprooster" placeholder="Max. capaciteit [dm3/s]"></td>
                  <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Verblijfsgebied"></td>
                  <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="" placeholder="Verblijfsruimte"></td>
                  <td><a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
               </tr>
             </table>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </table>
```

This is the JavaScript of the calculation:

```js
$('#lrooster, #caprooster').keyup(function(){
    var lrooster = parseFloat($('#lrooster').val());
    var caprooster = parseFloat($('#caprooster').val());

    $('#maxcaprooster').val(lrooster * caprooster );
});
```

If the linked code doesnt work good, here 's a [fiddle](https://fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Wiljan123/7ub1c6y0/)

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please edit your various code elements into one runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

**`#id`s Must be Unique, Duplicate `#id`s Invalidates HTML**

Never clone (or replicate) any element with an `#id`. In the **OP** (**O**riginal **P**ost), there are 3 `#id`s being duplicated each time a row is added, which are `#lrooster`, `#caprooster`, and `#maxcaprooster`. When the browser is directed to find an `#id`, it naturally assume there's only one `#id` to find and it stops once the first one is found. That is why the first row is the only one that works.

### Solution

Avoid using `#id` and use `.class` instead. This is especially important to remember if you are using jQuery because of it's versatility. In fact, you are more than likely to hinder the functionality of your code should you use `#id` so generously.

### Changes

**Upgrades**

- jQuery 3.6.0 Slim
- Bootstrap 5.1.3 CSS and JavaScript
- Bootstrap Icons 1.8.3 CSS

**Replacements**

- `.delegate()` is now [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
- `#id`s are now `.class`es
- `#lrooster`, `#caprooster`, and `#maxcaprooster` are now `.lrooster`, `.kaprooser`, and `.maxkaprooster` and each are [`type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)
- `confirm()` is now a [Bootstrap modal-dialog](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)
- Use of `data-*` to determine index position for serializing `#id`s is a lot of bookkeeping, so it is now a single `.active` class assigned to a `<tr>`.
- BS classes are assigned throughout the HTML.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Hide button.remove of the first row
$('.remove').hide();

// Click button.add...
$('.add').on('click', function(e) {
  // Clone the first row of tbody
  let copy = $('tbody tr:first').clone(true, true);
  // Clear all of it's inputs
  copy.find('input').val('');
  // Reset number inputs to 0
  copy.find('[type="number"]').val('0');
  // Show button.remove 
  copy.find('.remove').show()
  // Add clone to tbody
  $('tbody').append(copy);
});

// Click button.remove...
$('.remove').on('click', function(e) {
  // Add .active to the <tr> that contains clicked button
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass('active');
});

// Click button.confirm...
$('.confirm').on('click', function(e) {
  // Remove tr.active
  $('.active').remove();
});

// Click button.close...
$('.close').on('click', function(e) {
  // Remove .active from <tr>
  $('tr').removeClass('active');
});

// Enter data in any number input...
$('[type="number"]').on('input', function() {
  /*
  Reference <tr> that contains input that the user is currently
  interacting with
  */
  const $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  // Convert the values of .lrooster and .kaprooster of current row
  let L = parseFloat($row.find('.lrooster').val());
  let K = parseFloat($row.find('.kaprooster').val());
  /*
  If the product of .lrooster and .kaprooster equals NaN, retrun 0
  otherwise the product
  */
  let rooster = NaN ? 0 : L * K;
  // Display result in .maxkaprooster
  $row.find('.maxkaprooster').val(rooster);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main class="container-fluid">
  <section class='row'>
    <menu class='d-flex flex-row-reverse mt-1 mb-1'>
      <button class="add btn btn-primary" style='width: max-content;'><i class="bi bi-plus-lg"></i> Toevoegen </button>
    </menu>
    <table class="posts table table-stripped">
      <thead class='table table-dark'>
        <tr>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Grille Length</th>
          <th>Grille Type</th>
          <th>Capacity [dm³/s]</th>
          <th>Max. [dm³/s]</th>
          <th>Home</th>
          <th>Room</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"></td>
          <td><input name="lrooster" class="lrooster form-control" type="number" value='0'></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"></td>
          <td><input name="kaprooster" class="kaprooster form-control" type="number" value='0'></td>
          <td><input name="maxkaprooster" class="maxkaprooster form-control" type="number" readonly value='0'></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"></td>
          <td><button class="remove btn btn-xs" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal"><i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </section>

  <aside id='modal' class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <dialog class="modal-dialog" open>
      <article class="modal-content">
        <header class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Confirm Row Removal</h5>
          <button class="close btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-body">
          <p>Ventilatierooster verwijderen?</p>
        </section>
        <footer class="modal-footer">
          <button class="close btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button class="confirm btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Remove Row</button>
        </footer>
      </article>
    </dialog>
  </aside>

</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is because you're using `id` attributes in the HTML of each row which you clone. This causes duplicates which is invalid - `id` attribute values *must* be unique within the DOM. To fix this use common `class` attributes instead, to group elements by behaviour.

That said, there's also several other issues in your code which need to be addressed:

- Don't generate incremental `id` attributes at runtime. It's an anti-pattern which causes more bugs, additional complexity and makes the code more difficult to maintain. User common classes and DOM traversal methods to relate elements to each other as required.
- The version of jQuery you're using is outdated. Update to 3.6.0
- Bootstrap is outdated too, however I'll leave this as an exercise for the OP to update as there may be some breaking changes in moving to v5.
- Don't use inline styling on elements - use a stylesheet.
- `delegate()` was deprecated from jQuery a long time ago. Use `on()` instead.
- Use the `input` event instead of `keyup`. The latter does not listen for content added to the form control using the mouse, the former does.
- Use the `$` variable, where available to make your code more succinct. You can alias it through the document.ready handler if necessary.
- Use a `<template />` element to store HTML which will be used to create dynamic content at runtime.
- Give all form controls a name, even if you're submitting the form via AJAX.
- Use `data()` to access `data` attributes, not `attr()`.
- Create delegated event handlers for all dynamic content (ie. the `lrooster` and `caprooster` inputs)

With all those issues corrected, here's a working example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let rowHtml = $('#sample_table_venr').html();
  let appendRow = () => $('#tbl_posts_body_venr').append(rowHtml);

  appendRow(); // add a row on page load

  $(document).on('click', 'a.add-record_venr', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    appendRow(); // add a row on button click
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'a.delete-record', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (confirm("Ventilatierooster verwijderen?")) {
      $(e.target).closest('tr').remove();
    }
  });

  $(document).on('input', '.lrooster, .caprooster', e => {
    let $row = $(e.target).closest('tr');
    let lrooster = parseFloat($row.find('.lrooster').val()) || 0;
    let caprooster = parseFloat($row.find('.caprooster').val()) || 0;
    $row.find('.maxcaprooster').val(lrooster * caprooster);
  });
});
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin-left: 1px;
}

#tbl_posts_venr thead {
  background-color: #c7c8cc;
  width: 100% !important;
}

#tbl_posts_venr thead th:first-child {
  width: 30px;
}


/* only for this demo, to help the content fit in the snippet preview */
input {
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="wellclearfix">
  <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right add-record_venr" data-added="0">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Toevoegen
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-stripped" id="tbl_posts_venr">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Merk</th>
        <th>Lengte rooster</th>
        <th>Type rooster</th>
        <th>Capaciteit [dm3/s]</th>
        <th>Max. capaciteit [dm3/s]</th>
        <th>Verblijfsgebied</th>
        <th>Verblijfsruimte</th>
        <th>Verwijderen</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl_posts_body_venr"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<template id="sample_table_venr">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="merk" placeholder="Merk"> </td>
    <td><input class="inputtext lrooster" type="text" name="lrooster" placeholder="Lengte rooster"></td>
    <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="typerooster" placeholder="Type rooster"></td>
    <td><input class="inputtext caprooster" type="text" name="caprooster" placeholder="Capaciteit [dm3/s]"></td>
    <td><input class="inputtext maxcaprooster" type="text" name="maxcaprooster" placeholder="Max. capaciteit [dm3/s]"></td>
    <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="verblijfsgebied" placeholder="Verblijfsgebied"></td>
    <td><input class="inputtext" type="text" name="verblijfsruimte" placeholder="Verblijfsruimte"></td>
    <td>
      <a class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="1">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```